# Rails Server Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, puma

Randomly, and sometimes infrequently, and other times unusually frequently (like today ... barely can get anything running without being hit with `"We're sorry, but something went wrong."`)... and I have no idea how to fix it ... any advice would be appreciated.

And it's always the same error: `IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address`, ie, it's not related to Postgresql not running, etc, etc ...

Here's the output:

```
AA:nested_two aa$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for fe80::1%lo0 at 2016-08-23 13:51:48 -0700

IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:560:in `in6_addr'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:497:in `initialize'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:515:in `new'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:515:in `coerce_other'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ipaddr.rb:171:in `include?'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `block in include?'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `any?'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whitelist.rb:17:in `include?'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/request.rb:16:in `from_whitelisted_ip?'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/whiny_request.rb:8:in `from_whitelisted_ip?'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-3.3.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Maybe try forcing ipv4 - connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, how do I force `127.0.0.1`? When I tried that, it states that it's unable to connect ... and yes, the server is running ...

Comment: As in put http://127.0.0.1:3000 in the browser instead of localhost:3000

Comment: @FrederickCheung, that works ... but also this `http://localhost:3000` is also working *now* which is super annoying ... because I know in 5ish minutes or so, it'll stop working again, and I'll get hit with this weird error again ... is that any particular reason why that error keeps happening?!?!?!?

Comment: @FrederickCheung ... weird ... maybe I'm wrong ... because right now `http://localhost:3000/` is not working but this is working: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` ... any reason why?!?!?

Comment: That points to an ipv6 issue - localhost can resolve either to an ipv4 address (127.0.0.1) or an ipv6 one, and you have issues when it picks ipv6. Why the underlying issue is there i don't know

Comment: @FrederickCheung, ok, no worries. thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score -1):

There is some error due to corruption of browser. Open a new tab or restart your browser and try to access your rails application. It will work.